# Is it possible to put HTML code in innerHTML in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I tried the following code, but it isn't working.

```
<a href="#sample" onclick="document.getElementById('samplechange').innerHTML='<a href="#sample">SampleAfter</a>'>Sample change</a>
<p id="samplechange">SampleFirst</p>
```

Is it possible to put code in the innerHTML part of this code, or is it only possible to put plain text?
When I try this, I just get the code in the innerHTML part outside of the code...

Comment: This could be valid, if you properly escaped your quotes.  I'm absolutely not saying it is recommended though.

Comment: You didn't escape your quotes properly, that's why it's not working, try this:

`<a href="#sample" onclick="document.getElementById('samplechange').innerHTML='<a href=\'#sample\'>test</a>'">Sample change</a>
<p id="samplechange">SampleFirst</p>`

Answer (score 1):

@Owl already described the problem in your code. However, it is always a good idea to separate your HTML markup from your JavaScript code. One way of doing it would be the following:

```js
document.getElementById('a1').addEventListener('click',
function(){
 document.getElementById('samplechange').innerHTML='<a href="#sample">SampleAfter</a>'
});
```

```html
<a href="#sample" id="a1">Sample change</a>
<p id="samplechange">SampleFirst</p>
```

When you do it this way you don't even need to escape the quotes any more.